# how to print on pdf without html tags from mysql database?

Tags: html, mysql, pdf, tinymce, format

I have a project where i have to print questions from mysql database.

I type the questions using html rich text editor(tinymce).

When I print on pdf,it prints all the html tags.

What should I do?i need the formatting that I do on the rich text editor to appear on the pdf and not the html tags.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML and PDF are two different formats for representing documents for rendering. To enter documents in one format and render in another, you'll need to translate from one to the other using application code.

Have a look at this question and its several answers to see various ways how it can be done with PHP: [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: Is there any other way besides PHP?

Comment: Sure. Google "javascript convert html to pdf" or "python convert html to pdf" or whatever your language of choice is. Alternatively, you could use a simpler text editor and avoid adding formatting to your document, printing it as plain text. Alternatively, print it directly from a rendered HTML document in Javascript using the `Window.print()` method.

Comment: Thanks I used the htmlparser from itext

Comment: Great to hear it! Welcome to Stack Overflow, and don't forget to give yourself a more suitable name :)